# You already have stopped smoking by now(phrase)

Tags: grammar, phrases

Let's say you have a friend who can't stop smoking cigarette, and you don't believe him saying that he is concern about his health. And you say:

> "If you were really concern about your health, basically, **you already have stopped smoking by now."**

I think this is ungrammatical, is there any **correct phrase** to express what I am trying to say?

Comment: ... **is concerned** is correct.

Comment: you would have aleardy stopped smoking by now. - you could use "would" here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say:

"If you really were concerned about your health, you would have already stopped smoking by now."